# Request always returns 400 when sent from application (flask_corse)

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-cors

I have a backend is implemented in flask and flask_restful and has a number of different routes. My frontend is running on another origin which means that I used flask_curse in order to allow my frontend to sent requests to my backend.

Bellow you can see the initialization of my application:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(check_routes_page)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

Here is the route I am calling from the front-end:

```
@check_routes_page.route(API_URL +API_VERSION +'check/email', methods=['POST'])
def check_email():
    email = request.form['email']
    user = User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()
    if user:
        return jsonify({'success':True}), 200
    else:
        return jsonify({'success': False}), 404
```

When I use Postman to sent the request everything works perfectly. When I do however sent a request from my application I always get back a 400. I have also change the content type without any success.

Here is the request I sent from my application.

```
checkMailAddress(email: string): boolean {

        let requestUrl = 'http://X/application/api/V0.1/check/email';
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
        let body = JSON.parse('{"email":"' + email + '"}');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let respo: any
        let us = this.http.post(requestUrl, body, options)
            .map((response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(
            function(response) {
                console.log("Success Response:" + response);
                respo = response;

            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("Error happened" + error);
            },
            function() {
                console.log("the subscription is completed");
                console.log(respo.status);
            }
            );
        return true;
    }
```

When I sent a request with content type Json the client sends an option request first (which returns code 200) but than still fails with the actual request.

I am thankful for any hints or advice.

Comment: man, I dont think posting your ip is a good idea...

Comment: It is not the real ip :). I changed it. But thank you.

Comment: Did you try Content-Type `application/json`? Cause you are sending JSON data in body and not urlencoded data.

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well. Unfortunately it does not work either..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

`user = User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()`

to:

`user = User.query.filter(email=email).first()`

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Unfortunately it does not work. I think the problem is related to the corse calls.

Answer (score 0):

When this line fails `email = request.form['email']` then flask sends 400 bad request.
Check if the request body is json or any other type using `request.isjson()` if not then convert data to json using `data = request.getjson()`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Request has no function isjson() or getjson().